# Dar formato a campos numericos de Django en template

Tags: django, formato, django-templates

Recibo en mis templates algunos datos numericos desde una vista, por ejemplo un salario para este caso practico 100.000:

```
<td>{{ role.salary }}</td>
```

Pero en el tenplate me lo muestra con x decimales:

> 100000,33333333

Como puedo darle formato de por ejemplo 2 decimales o ningun decimal en el template ?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encontre la forma, usando un template filter y definiendo la cantidad de decimales:

```
{{ role.salary|floatformat:2 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pondría esto como un comentario, pero no tengo suficiente reputacion...
Considera también usar los filtros de [humanize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/humanize/) de django. Tiene opciones de localizacion para usar el formato numerico apropiado en cada país y mas funcionalidad para formatear números